# error accessing spring boot application via localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, networking, localhost

I try to access localhost:8080/hello but appeals localhost:8080/login the only things that shows is status code 302 on network status and shows that hello.html has no initiator and initiator hello is on login

```
     package com.example.biblioteca;
      import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
      import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

     @SpringBootApplication
     public class BibliotecaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BibliotecaApplication.class, args);
      }

    }
Controller class

      package com.example.biblioteca.controller;

     import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

     @Controller
     public class HelloControler {
    
      @GetMapping("/hello")
       public String hello() {
         return "hello";
     }
     }

html file:
  <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset ="UTF-8"/>
       
        </head>
       <body>
         hello working
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: please share your `pom.xml` file (if you use maven)

Comment: pleae share your application.properties too.

Comment: @mr155 https://pastebin.com/9a3DXsXC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to use security, just delete or comment this dependency from your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> when you use `spring-security` you have to pass the authentication
> before any action.

if you want to use security, add this security configs to the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.security.user.name=custom-username
spring.security.user.password=custom-password
```